# Generating Child Object when mapping father Enum(Fluent Nhibernate)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance, enums, fluent-nhibernate

I am doing some project and I have encountered some problem which I don't know if it can be solved.
So my problem is like this:

I have 4 classes in my project:

```
public abstract class ABaseDynamicLayer
{
    public virtual int LayerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string URIPath { get; set; }
}

public class RasterDynamicLayer : ABaseDynamicLayer
{
}

public class TerrainDynamicLayer : ABaseDynamicLayer
{
}

public class VectorDynamicLayer : ABaseDynamicLayer
{
}
```

Now my DB looks like that:

T_DYNAMIC_LAYERS

```
ID  |   URIPath  |  TYPE  |
---------------------------
1   | c:\map1.mp |   1    |
2   | c:\map2.mp |   3    |
3   | c:\map5.mp |   2    |
```

T_TYPES

```
ID  |  DESCRIPTION  |
---------------------
1   |  Raster       |
2   |  Terrain      |
3   |  Vector       |
```

Now my goal is to map T_DYNAMIC_LAYERS to my project and while I do this I do not want to save the type of the layer, instead I want to create the fitting object from my class list as their type mentioned in the T_DYNAMIC_LAYERS.

For Example:

Let's say we are in the progress of mapping the first row in T_DYNAMIC_LAYERS.
1) We map the ID column to the ID property.
2) We map the URIPath Column to the URIPath to the URIPath property.

That is easy an nice but the wanted result after all this is that I want to get an object of RasterDynamicLayer from the first row since the type in the row is 1(1 equals to RasterDynamicLayer).

Can it be done?
If it can be done, how can I do it?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is this of any help? http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/08/fluent-nhibernate-table-inheritance-discriminators/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [factory pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx)
The simple example of use:

```
enum LayerType
{
    Raster,
    Terrain,
    Vector
}

public static ABaseDynamicLayer CreateLayer(LayerType type, int id, string uri)
{
    ABaseDynamicLayer layer;
    switch (type)
    {
        case LayerType.Raster:
            layer = new RasterDynamicLayer();
            break;
        case LayerType.Terrain:
            layer = new TerrainDynamicLayer();
            break;
        case LayerType.Vector:
            layer = new VectorDynamicLayer();
            break;
        default: throw new ArgumentException("Type not supported:" + type.ToString()); 
    }
    layer.LayerID = id;
    layer.URIPath = uri;
    return layer;
}
```

Comment: I can't use the factory since I want to build an engine which creates the object while mapping occurs